# Refrigerator leaks

Tags: refrigerator

I have a refrigerator with the freezer on top, It freezes and cools just fine but there is water leaking down from the freezer to the refrigerator area. What could be the problem?

Comment: Frost free? Freezer drain line is probably blocked w minerals or mold. They can tell you how to clean it over at Home Improvement Stack. Brand model and year of fridge would be helpful information.

Comment: Kitchen equipment has long ago been declared on topic on the site, see http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/138/are-questions-about-equipment-off-topic and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. If the community wants to change the rules, we will have to make a Meta discussion, but currently, this question is fully in scope and shouldn't be closed as off topic.

Comment: I think this is probably a candidate for migration.  It's not necessarily off-topic, as equipment questions are important, but it's likely a maintenance issue and those don't seem to get great answers here.  We seem to do better with equipment selection and usage questions.

Comment: I know there's not a ton of information here (and the OP is unregistered) but I went ahead and migrated this because it went a week without anyone even trying to answer, and I think it's likely to do better here.